# EM vs. direct numerical optimization of likelihood function in high-dimensional Markov-Switching / HMM

Tags: optimization, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

I am currently estimating a Markov-switching model with many parameters using direct optimization of the log likelihood function (through the forward-backward algorithm). I do the numerical optimization using matlab's genetic algorithm, since other approaches such as the (mostly gradient or simplex-based) algorithms in fmincon and fminsearchbnd were not very useful, given that likelihood function is not only of very high dimension but also shows many local maxima and is highly nonlinear. The genetic algorithm seems to work very well. However, I am planning to further increase the dimension of the problem. I have read about an EM algorithm to estimate Markov-Switching models. From what I understand this algorithm releases a sequence of increasing log-likelhood values. I thus seems suitable to estimate models with very many parameters.

**My question is if the EM algorithm is suitable for my application involving many parameters (perhaps better suitable as the genetic algorithm). Speed is not the first main limitattion (the genetic algorithm is altready extremely slow) but I would need to have some certainty to end up close to the global optimum and not run into one of the many local optima. Do you have any experience or suggestions regarding this?**